# How to remove grand totals in R using the RpivoTable library?

Tags: r, powerbi, rpivottable

I am using the rpivotTable library but I can't find how to remove the grand totals from the result table. Has anyone had the same problem?

I have searched the library documentation but it only shows how to remove the subtotals, but I can't find anything about the totals.

Comment: Hi Pawel! Is this helpful? https://github.com/smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable/issues/63